# microdata type for fan levels

Tags: microdata, schema.org

When I used the [Google structured data markup helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) it offered me the category software which seems quite to fit to my website project which offers fan mission downloads for games.
But this category is refering to [SoftwareApplication](http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication) from schema.org. And a fan mission isn't an application. **What is your advice I should use?**

SoftwareApplication would offer *downloadUrl, fileSize, fileFormat, screenshot & softwareVersion* which I currently use.
When I use CreativeWork (Which could be anything!) instead I would lost those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use CreativeWork and still give it attributes from Software. Once you do that, e.g. to a test page, you can use Structured Data Testing Tool to see how Google recognized your markup:
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Your use case is described in schema.org docs here:

http://schema.org/docs/faq.html#12

Comment: Where exactly do you think this use case is described? I can’t find it. AFAIK you are not allowed to use undefined properties for defined itemtypes.